# Google Apps Script | How to access Row/Column data for certain ranges

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm brand new to Google app scripts and wanted to create an automation script for data I am collecting through a google form.

I have 3 fields that users fill out in a form that populate columns in a sheet.

[Google Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhoGb.jpg)

From the responses, I want to automatically generate a database entry for another scripting language "Papyrus" by simply writing out the code as a modified concatenated string.

ex.

```
   GasMaskM1A211.PluginFile = Context.Plugin
   GasMaskM1A211.FormID = 0x00007A77
   GasMaskM1A211.TypeClass = ClassGasMask
   Add(GasMaskM1A211)
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about accessing the data (Strings) from the columns and writing to a separate column that will have the concatenated string.

So far, I've tried to follow a few examples online that did similar but not quite what I was trying to accomplish and this was the result.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastRow = range.getLastRow();

function onOpen(e) {
  getValues();
}

function getValues() {
  var sortColumnRange = sheet.getRange("B2:D100");
  var sortColumnVals = sortColumnRange.getValues();
  var cell;
  for(var i = 1; i < sortColumnVals.length; i++){
    if(sortColumnVals[i][0] !== ""){
      var armorName = sortColumnVals[i][3].toString()
      var formID = sortColumnVals[i][2].toString()
      var pluginName = sortColumnVals[i][1].toString();
      pluginName.replace(" ","_");
      pluginName.replace(".esp","_ESP");
      pluginName.replace(".esm","_ESM");
      var entry = "string " + pluginName + " = " + sortColumnVals[i][0].toString() + "\n";
      entry = entry + "Entry " + armorName + " =  New Entry \n";
      entry = entry + armorName + ".PluginFile = " + pluginName + "\n";
      entry = entry + armorName + ".FormID = " + formID + "\n";
      entry = entry + armorName + ".TypeClass = ClassGasMask \n";
      entry = entry + "Add(" + armorName + ")";
      Logger.log(entry);
      cell = sheet.getRange(i, 5);
      cell.setValue(entry);
    }
  }
}
```

There are no apparent error messages, but I get the feeling that I am not accessing the right cells. Nothing gets printed to the log nor entered into the sheet.

Comment: When you say that nothing gets printed into the log, do you mean nothing at all, a blank space, a blank array? Also, why do you start your loop at `i=1`?

Comment: I started with i = 1 due to a misunderstanding. I was getting an error at 0 that turned out it was unrelated to  the index. I also got slightly confused due to the difference between the array indexing and the actual sheet indexing (which starts at 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your array indexes. In Javascript (and thus Google Script), array indexes start at 0. So you should decrease all your index numbers with 1, and I believe it will work (at least, when quickly tested, it *does* return something, although I can't assess whether that's what you'd expect or not).

```
function getValues() {
  var sortColumnRange = sheet.getRange("B2:D100");
  var sortColumnVals = sortColumnRange.getValues();
  var cell;
  for(var i = 0; i < sortColumnVals.length; i++){
    if(sortColumnVals[i][0] !== ""){
      var armorName = sortColumnVals[i][2].toString()
      var formID = sortColumnVals[i][1].toString()
      var pluginName = sortColumnVals[i][0].toString();
      pluginName.replace(" ","_");
      pluginName.replace(".esp","_ESP");
      pluginName.replace(".esm","_ESM");
      var entry = "string " + pluginName + " = " + sortColumnVals[i][0].toString() + "\n";
      entry = entry + "Entry " + armorName + " =  New Entry \n";
      entry = entry + armorName + ".PluginFile = " + pluginName + "\n";
      entry = entry + armorName + ".FormID = " + formID + "\n";
      entry = entry + armorName + ".TypeClass = ClassGasMask \n";
      entry = entry + "Add(" + armorName + ")";
      Logger.log(entry);
      cell = sheet.getRange(i, 5);
      cell.setValue(entry);
    }
  }
}
```